# How to select items from IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

My `ordersInfo` variable has type `IEnumerable<Order>`. `Order` is a custom object. I try to make selection like this:

```
var s = ordersInfo.Select(x => x.Customer.Email == user.Email && x.Status == OrderStatus.Paid).ToList();
```

But it returns a collection of 161 elements (it is initial count of collection) and each item has value `false`. It is not `Order` object either. What is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps SQL is a relevant precedent here. In SQL both `select *` and `select columnA, columnB` give you every record.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like you want the Where statement, not the Select statement. Select is used to transform one object into another or select only specific parts of a given object. Where is used to filter.

```
var s = ordersInfo.Where(x => x.Customer.Email == user.Email 
  && x.Status == OrderStatus.Paid).ToList();
```

Comment: What are those objects involved in the transformation?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for `Where` instead of `Select`.

```
var s = ordersInfo
   .Where(x => x.Customer.Email == user.Email && 
               x.Status == OrderStatus.Paid)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

`Select` is a projection or a conversion for each item. Think like the `SELECT` clause of SQL - it changes the output. You want to use `Where` which is a deferred filtering.

Comment: Sounds like the OP is new to LINQ.  Might not be a bad idea to define what a "projection" is and how it differs from a "deferred filtering."

Answer (score 3):

[**From MSDN - IEnumerable.Select**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

> *Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.*
>
> **Remarks**
>
> *This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.
>   This projection method requires the transform function, selector, to produce one value for each value in the source sequence, source. If selector returns a value that is itself a collection, it is up to the consumer to traverse the subsequences manually. In such a situation, it might be better for your query to return a single coalesced sequence of values. To achieve this, use the SelectMany method instead of Select. Although SelectMany works similarly to Select, it differs in that the transform function returns a collection that is then expanded by SelectMany before it is returned.*
>
> *In query expression syntax, a select (Visual C#) or Select (Visual Basic) clause translates to an invocation of Select.*

```
IEnumerable<int> squares = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x * x);
squares.ToList().ForEach(num => Console.WriteLine(num));
```

The output will be:

```
  1
  4
  9
 16
 25
 36
 49
 64
 81
100
```

You may also use the **IEnumerable.Select** to only select a fewer properties as well from an object, which will cause the creation of an [**anonymous type**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

What you want is to use the `IEnumerable.Where()` method.

[**From MSDN - IEnumerable.Where**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

> *Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.*
>
> **Remarks**
>
> *This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.*
>
> *In query expression syntax, a where (Visual C#) or Where (Visual Basic) clause translates to an invocation of `Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`.*

**To answer your question**

Use the **Where** method like so.

```
var s = ordersInfo.Where(x => x.Customer.Email == user.Email 
                           && x.Status == OrderStatus.Paid)
    .ToList();
```

Which will actually filter the list based on the criterion given as the predicate, and the list shall get filtered upon the call of the `ToList()` method, as `Where<T>` is deferred filtering.